# Return Response JSON and also Download in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I have function in controller. How can i return a json also with download a file?

I've has tried like this. but it's not working.

```
    public function downloadWithJson($request)
    {
       ....
       ....

       return response()->json([
         'status' => 'ok',
         'data' => (array data)
       ])->download(public_path($path));
    }
```

Comment: I think you can't do that. But let's see if it's possible.

Comment: either you return an "application/json" response or "image/jpeg" response (for example). What else you can do, return an "application/json" and in one of the date the base 64 encoded string of the file that you manipulate client site to generate a file download.

Answer (score 0):

```
   use File;
    .....
    .....
    
    $data = json_encode($dataArray);
    $fileName = time() . '_datafile.json';
    $fileStorePath = public_path('/upload/json/'.$fileName);
    File::put($fileStorePath, $data);
    return response()->json(
     'status' => 'ok',
     'data' => $dataArray,
     'url  => $fileStorePath
);
```

Comment: your solution propose to send the path of the file instead of the file itself. Mind adding more details about your answer ?